# Passing a bash command line arguments containing #

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal

I am trying to pass pound sign as a command line argument then echoing the argument. When I pass for example 2 # 2 then I echo $1 $2 $3, I assume the terminal will output 2 # 2 but it outputs just 2. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible if you use bash as your shell (but as said above you can escape it, or you can put it in quotation marks).

However it will work fine if you launch your program from csh for example.

Answer (score 4):

`#` is the comment character. If you don't want it to be, you need to either escape it, or quote it.

```
echo 2 \# 2
echo 2 '#' 2
```

Comment: I have an assignment in which it says when the command is for example 2 # 2, the output should be "Error". So I shouldn't write a backslash before the pound sign or wrap it around quotes. Just #.

Comment: @Altaïr I'm afraid I do not understand what you are saying, or how it relates to your question.

Comment: There is no way to write a program that can distinguish between `prog 2 # 2` and `prog 2`.

Comment: However, if there is no space before the #. it is not considered a comment. So `prog 2#2` has one argument, which is `2#2`.

Comment: Also, in an *interactive* shell, the `#` is only a comment if the `interactive_comments` option is set

Comment: Is it possible that the question really means "any number" in place of "#" ?